# Re-Containing MDIchild forms

Tags: c#, vb.net, mdichild

I am converting a windows forms application from VB to C#.

In short, i have a method in a formLocation() class where a form is passed in (fires during double click) and the form can be reset as an MDIChild of MainForm.  For some reason, this VB code does not translate to C#.  Its forcing me to make a new instance of MainForm which is not ideal because the child form must go into the current instance of MainForm.  Here is the VB code:  Basically I just need the C# equivalent:

```
Public Sub contain(ByVal form As Form)
    With form
        .MdiParent = MainForm
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If it needs to go into the instance, then pass the instance of MainForm to the method... I don't see what the issue is. Also hence why it's requiring you to make a new instance because it doesn't know what MainForm is...

Comment: Unlearning the dreaded default instance feature of VB.NET is going to take a while.  Simplest workaround is form.MdiParent = Application.OpenForms[0];

Answer (score 0):

VB creates a default instance of forms which is accessed by the same name as the form class, which historically has caused a lot of confusion - all in the name of saving a couple of lines of code.

In your 'MainForm' class, insert the following:

```
private static MainForm _DefaultInstance;
public static MainForm DefaultInstance
{
    get
    {
        if (_DefaultInstance == null)
            _DefaultInstance = new MainForm();

        return _DefaultInstance;
    }
}
```

Now, change your code to:

```
form.MdiParent = MainForm.DefaultInstance;
```

This is the closest way to reproduce what VB does for you, but you should eventually move to a more standard way of instantiating your forms.

Converting VB to C#, you'll come across many other cases where VB's good intention of hiding details from programmers has prevented basic understanding of programming concepts (such as instance vs type).

Comment: And yes!  i have encountered "endless" situations where VB's "good intentions" have cause me some  headache.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That explains a lot!  however, this does not error, but the form does not return back to mainForm.  Double clicking when its mdiparent = null does not reset it back to main form

Comment: @Matt That's because you need a reference to that main form instance as said in my comments above. Creating a new one will not help as its not the instance you are after...

Comment: @Zaggler - i put the code in as you instructed.  Still a no go.